# Some questions related to a complicated function

Tags: calculus, integration, number-theory, trigonometric-integrals

Consider $$f(x)=\cos(\cos(\cos(x)))+\cos(\cos(\sin(x)))+\cos(\sin(\cos(x)))+\cos(\sin(\sin(x)))+\sin(\cos(\cos(x)))+\sin(\cos(\sin(x)))+\sin(\sin(\cos(x)))+\sin(\sin(\sin(x)))$$

In short, $f(x)$ is the sum of all possible compositions of the functions $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ with depth $3$.

I am interested in $3$ numbers related to the function :

The minimum of the function

$$f(\frac{\pi}{4})=3.2103446496560662265706969\cdots$$

The maximum of the function

$$f(\frac{5\pi}{4})= 5.62993400541747848130595\cdots$$

The integral

$$\int_{x=0}^{2\pi} f(x)\ dx= 27.77165132853786021829975\cdots$$

Questions :

- Is there a closed formula for the three numbers ?
- Are the three numbers rational, irrational algebraic or transcendental ?
- Does anyone know a good approximation of $f(x)$ in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ ? The maximal error should be less than $0.001$.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed" formula ? The formula for $f(\pi/4)$ is $\cos(\cos(\cos(\pi/4)))+\ldots$, so quite nice. What do you think about the second question - all irrational, it seems?

Comment: I mean a closed form less complicated than the expression given by the function. I conjecture the three numbers are transcendental.

Comment: And I conjecture that the three numbers are rational......

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can collapse the minimum to four terms, as in

$$f(\pi/4) = 2\left[\sin(\sin(1/\sqrt{2})) + \sin(\cos(1/\sqrt{2})) + \cos(\sin(1/\sqrt{2})) + \cos(\cos(1/\sqrt{2}))\right],$$

but that's probably only, um, minimally satisfying.

Comment: I agree that it is not really satisfying.